# Symfony 4 Routes

Tags: routes, annotations, symfony4

Starting project on Symfony 4. But i got problem. When i using new route, I get "No route found". But similar route is correct.
Command debug:router showing old routes, clearing cash doen't work for me, I used

```
1)php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
2)php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
3)php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

[debug:router result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgXSb.png)
Even route names is incorrect.

routes.yaml is empty (using Annotations).
My Controller:

```
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Entity\Subcategory;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * Matches / exactly
     *
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Product::class)
            ->findDiscounts();
        $categories = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Category::class)
            ->findAll();
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', compact('products', 'categories'));
    }

    /**
     * Matches /shop/*
     *
     * @Route("/shop/{categoryAlias}", name="shop_show")
     * @param string $categoryAlias
     * @return Response
     */
    public function shop($categoryAlias = 'null')
    {
        if ($categoryAlias != 'null') :
            $response = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(Category::class)
                ->findbyAlias($categoryAlias);
            $categories = array(); //Костыль
            $categories[] = $response; //Костыль
            $subcategories = $categories[0]->getSubcategories();
        else :
            $categories = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(Category::class)
                ->findAll();
            $subcategories = null;
        endif;
        $allCategories = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Category::class)
            ->findAll();
        return $this->render('default/shop.html.twig', compact('allCategories','subcategories','categories'));
    }

    /**
     * Matches /product/*
     *
     * @Route("/product/{productAlias}", name="product_show")
     * @param string $productAlias
     * @return Response
     */
    public function product($productAlias)
    {
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Product::class)
            ->findByAlias($productAlias);
        return $this->render('default/product.html.twig', compact('product'));
    }
}
```

Route /shop is working. Route /product is not.
I'm only starting in Symfony, and stuck here.
Thanks.

Comment: I got similar problem before, check if there are duplicate/same route name for 2 different paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually deleted the folder "cache", all works